# Asymptotic curves of hyperboloid of one sheet

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

There is an exercise in Manfredo do Carmo's book,page172,that aks about the asymptotic curves of $x^2+y^2-z^2=1$. I used the formula $e(u')^2+2fu'v'+g(v´)^2=0$ where $e,f,g$ are the coefficients of the second fundamental form.I got this

$$ (u^2+v^2-1)((u´)^2+(v')^2)=u(u')^2-2uu'vv'+v(v')^2$$

but I have no idea how to proceed to find $u$ and $v$. Any ideas?

Comment: Your title is wrong. This is a hyperboloid of *one* sheet. The distinction is *essential*. The hyperboloid of two sheets is everywhere *positively* curved!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, what parametrization are you using? Second of all, there is a fundamental geometric fact you should know about the hyperboloid of one sheet (or the hyperbolic paraboloid, saddle surface) — it is doubly ruled. Through each point of the surface there are two lines contained in the surface.

Comment: I am using $\phi(u,v)=(u,v,\sqrt(u^2+v^2-1))$ for $z>0$. I am sorry, I did not understand how your second statement can help me.

Comment: What @TedShifrin is saying is that this surface can be thought as a [faggot of spaghetti](https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/spaghetti-in-the-form-of-a-sheaf-picture-id479580386?s=612x612), and that moreover, you can use a mirror symmetry to see that it has two such strucutres.

Comment: Forget about differential equations. What is the geometric definition of an asymptotic curve?

Comment: It is a regular curve $\alpha$ where the normal curvature at $\alpha'$ is zero.

Comment: OK, and do you know a result relating normal curvature of $\alpha$ and curvature of $\alpha$?

Comment: I am sorry, yes I do. $k_n=k_\alpha\times cos(\theta)$. And you mean that I can conclude that the normal vector at the surface and the curve normal vector are perpendicular, i.e, $cos(\theta)=0$?

Comment: Well, in this case, the curve — being a line — has no principal normal vector!! What is its curvature, however?